# How to use command line flags in Linux?

Tags: wallet, linux, error

I'm using bitcoin-qt(0.8.0) on ubuntu studio (12.04.2), and suffered a power failure while loading. Now I receive the "failed to load block" error message.

This happened to someone else, and the answer he was given which solved his problem was to run it from the command line and use the -reindex flag.
I'm hopeful this might work for me as well, but I don't know how to go about it.

I know how to access "terminal", but I don't really mess with it. I'm at a loss.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Close Bitcoin.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Type `bitcoin-qt -reindex`
4. Press enter.

Comment: This answer even made me laugh :)

Comment: @StevenRoose Huh? Why?

Comment: Just because how simple it is, but still non-trivial :p
Btw, I changed the question title to be more clear.